# how to get data of another field in wtform validate_?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to do password validation on wtform like this:

```
email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
def validate_password(self, password):
        print(self)
        user = dbSession.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email",
            {"email": self.email.data}
        ).fetchone()
        print(user)
        if not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password.data):
            raise ValidationError('Incorrect Password.')
```

i want to get the email from other field, but i guess it's not working, i tried email.data but it isn't defined. also, it's not logging in console. in js, you log an object like this. I wanted to see the self's properties and the user, i want to log like this in python.

```
console.log('user =', user);
```

help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer reformulates [this little snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/64/)

> Sometimes you are in the situation where you need to validate a form with custom logic that can not necessarily be reduced to a validator on a single field. A good example are login forms where you have to make sure a user exists in the database and has a specific password.

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    email = TextField('Email', [validators.InputRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [validators.InputRequired()])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.user = None

    def validate(self):
        rv = Form.validate(self)
        if not rv:
            return False

        user = User.query.filter_by(
            email=self.email.data).first()
        if user is None:
            self.email.errors.append('Unknown email')
            return False

        if not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, self.password.data):
            self.password.errors.append('Invalid Password')               
            return False

        self.user = user
        return True
```